# Sitecore 10.1.2 Identity server issue - Windows 11

Tags: identity-server

I have installed the `Sitecore 10.1.2` version in `Windows 11`. Now, I'm getting the error, when I try to log in to the `Sitecore` backend, the IDentity server is throwing this error.

This is the error I could see on the screen:

```
Sorry, there was an error: invalid_request
```

Error in a log file:

```
("redirect_uri": "https://my.local.sc/identity/signin"), ("sc_account_prefix": "sitecore\"), ("x-client-SKU": "ID_NET461"), ("x-client-ver": "5.3.0.0")] }

2022-03-18T11:47:03.9307641+05:30 

[INF] (Sitecore Identity/DESKTOP-MSLEBO1) Request finished in 
11.956ms 302 
2022-03-18T11:47:03.9360478+05:30 [INF] (Sitecore Identity/DESKTOP- 
MSLEBO1) Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET 
http://my.local.identityserver/home/error? 
errorId=CfDJ8BOeOQDkhT5AvugX- 0yD82bgf62cx3jw0ih2i8LXyKyIeT7PdNVYyuPe9l2afxJVRbC3O5_2e7yPkVnyxRC9TRkv1bRq4oNc8nRVKcOIJpyCnQje4tgXNZv5Xl5jxucEUekbFE7lfjNkJ489AlQaL5kea7SrQG-UwKwJXM-OuV4XupntoZAMthSH3Gz9wWnwhF1YzN7VBLtHSN1SOqDUcVqbDYpuTTxTITUwCxI_wCnvysCRqSMV9XGMsVgnI8QzTsCGuxZLwBcil7G1pfp2yzpfo_ZGhG3TuFI7VUOv-1NVyQTwWU0lfh2Qt1k-Kljj2klWbPV8XiFGXV5R2FtEHMM 


2022-03-18T11:47:03.9373514+05:30 

[INF] (Sitecore Identity/DESKTOP-MSLEBO1) Executing endpoint '"Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.HomeController.Error (Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer)"'

2022-03-18T11:47:03.9385973+05:30 
[INF] (Sitecore Identity/DESKTOP) Route matched with "{action = \"Error\", controller = \"Home\"}". Executing controller action with signature "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] Error(System.String)" on controller "Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer.Controllers.HomeController" ("Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer").
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out this issue? I am getting the same thing.

Comment: No @ZachGreen.But I have used the shortcut of ignoring the identity server. just appendfbc=1 that will pass the identity server

Comment: I figured out my problem. I was using a hostname that was not setup to be able to access the admin backend.